# Animation and randomiser using html/ js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a page of code in which i want 3 "ghost.png" to be displayed onto a canvas with random coordinates using math.random at a press of a button. Beyond that im also trying to use another function to draw "sac.jpg" onto the canvas aswell as drawing the same ghosts on the same positions as they have been determined by math.random. then in the same function, i want to be able to animate the image "sac.png" using the arrow keys on the keyboard without making the ghost image move along with it. With this goal, i tried to create a code but it does not seem to work. can someone explain?

recap:
function hasard (activates when button is pressed): 
a) math.random 6 times to choose x,y coordinates of 3 of the same image
b) place the image in a variable

function dessiner (activates when arrow key is pressed):
a) draw background
b) draw the image from function hasard in the same spot each time until i press the button from the first function to randomize a new pair of coordinates.
c) draw the image "sac.gif" and program it to be able to move using arrow keys.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Jeu.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"
    style="border-color: 'black'; border-width: 3px; border-style: solid">
      </canvas>
<br>
  <button type="button"onclick="hasard()"><img src="start.jpg"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var contexte = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x;
var y;
var x1;
var y1;
var x2;
var y2;

var ghost = new Image();
ghost.src = "ghost.png";

function hasard(){
x = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
y = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
x1 = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
y1 = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
x2 = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));
y2 = 32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));

contexte.drawImage(ghost,x,y,60,60)
contexte.drawImage(ghost,x1,y1,60,60)
contexte.drawImage(ghost,x2,y2,60,60)
};

var bg = new Image();
bg.src = 'haunted.jpg';

var sac = new Image();
sac.src = "sac.gif";

var a=100;
var b=100;
var dx=0;
var dy=0;

T_fleche_gauche = 37;
T_fleche_droite = 39;
T_fleche_haut = 38;
T_fleche_bas = 40;

document.onkeydown = miseAJourTouche;

function miseAJourTouche(e){

toucheCourante = e.keyCode;

if (toucheCourante == T_fleche_gauche){
dx= -1;
dy=0;
draw(dx,dy);
}
if (toucheCourante == T_fleche_droite){
dx= 1;
dy=0;
draw(dx,dy);
}
if (toucheCourante == T_fleche_haut){
dy= -1;
dx=0;
draw(dx,dy);
}
if (toucheCourante == T_fleche_bas){
dy= 1;
dx=0;
draw(dx,dy);
}
}

function dessiner(x,y){

bg.addEventListener('load', function() {

contexte.drawImage(bg, 100, 20, 200, 200);

image.onload = function(){
contexte.drawImage(ghost,x,y,60,60)
contexte.drawImage(ghost,x1,y1,60,60)
contexte.drawImage(ghost,x2,y2,60,60)

image.onload = function(){

context.drawImage(sac, 0, 0, 70,90);
context.translate(10+a,10+b);

a = a+dx;
b = b+dy;

if (a > 400) a = -80;  if (a <-80) a = 400;
if (b > 400) b = -40;  if (b <-40) b = 400;
}
window.requestAnimFrame(function() { dessiner(dx,dy) });
}
dessiner();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to draw **3 ghosts** with **random** positions, and a **bag** also at a **random** position, and would like to be able to move it with the **arrow keys**, is that right?

Then, I may suggest several things:

1. Don't put the update and drawing codes together. You have a drawing function `dessiner(x, y)` but you also draw in the `hasard()` and `miseAJourTouche(e)` functions. This makes things confusing and doesn't help debugging.
2. Factorize more: for example, in your `hasard()` function, you makes the calculations `32 +(Math.random() * (400-64));` 6 times. Instead, you could use a function to generate a random number between two values, then initialize your values in an `init()` function. You can initialize all the variables inside as well as load your images. Depending on what you aim to make, you could also use objects, like a `Ghost` object that would initialize its coordinates, with its own `draw()` method, etc. It could be much simpler for the rest.
3. Be consistent: if you put spaces before and after a `+`, then do it all the time. Don't use multiple languages inside the same code, you used both English and French (and English makes things easier when asking for help). Also, you can use a tool such as your IDE beautifier function or an online one (I used https://beautifier.io/) to make your code more readable or spot typing issues, like missing curly braces.

I took the liberty of refactoring your code a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/nmerinian/t0c3sh8f/4/

**Notes**:

- I didn't write any condition to prevent the refresh if no key is
  pressed, but it's easy to add.
- I commented the background drawing part since I don't have the image.
- I also commented some variables I didn't use.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you are trying to animate ghosts and bag, with the bag being the player controllable item.

While I can't debug the program for you, I can help telling you to use the dev tools of your browser. `F12` or `Fn + F12` will bring you to the Inspector, where one of the other tabs is console.

Now, in your program, I see you assign `image.onload` to two functions, with one of them missing a closing curly brace.

```
image.onload = function(){
contexte.drawImage(ghost,x,y,60,60)
contexte.drawImage(ghost,x1,y1,60,60)
contexte.drawImage(ghost,x2,y2,60,60)

image.onload = function(){

context.drawImage(sac, 0, 0, 70,90);
context.translate(10+a,10+b);

a = a+dx;
b = b+dy;

if (a > 400) a = -80;  if (a <-80) a = 400;
if (b > 400) b = -40;  if (b <-40) b = 400;
}
```

I would add a curly brace after the three calls to `contexte.drawImage`, but I question the choice for two assignments. Also, I don't think `image` is declared in this scope, but I might be wrong. That's all I see.

Comment: Why did [Barudar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5172900/barudar) copy my answer? It was also my first. :(